# Why am I getting warnings that analysers are not found?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-11.0, .net-7.0

I created a toy project for checking out the latest .NET 7 (preview-5) and the regex code generation. It worked great, so I applied the same changes to an existing project (not for production, but for personal productivity). For some reason, I’m getting these warnings:

```
CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.ValidateFormatString.CSharpValidateFormatStringDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.5.22307.18\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\codestyle\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden..
CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.UseUTF8StringLiteral.UseUTF8StringLiteralDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.5.22307.18\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\codestyle\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle.dll : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..
CS8033  The assembly C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.5.22307.18\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\codestyle\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeStyle.dll does not contain any analyzers.
```

The text *Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden..* translates to “The system cannot find the specified file,” but this is a DeepL translation and the actual English error message may be different.

Of the first two, it’s over 200 similar-spirited them with differing analyzers.

The toy project was a console application, the problematic project is a Windows Forms application, if this is somehow relevant. This is the – I believe – relevant part of the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AnalysisLevel>latest-all</AnalysisLevel>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>True</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Svg" Version="3.4.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningLevel>1</WarningLevel>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>True</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningLevel>1</WarningLevel>
    <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>True</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I also tried commenting-out the Svg dependency and the code that uses it. That changed nothing notably.

And, for comparison and completion, this is the `.csproj` file of the toy project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I do not understand why the analyzers aren’t found. The DLLs are definitely there. I suspect that it’s the `Version=4.3.0.0` part, but I have no idea what that version refers to, which one would be correct and where I’d specify that.

One answer I found told me to use `<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows;netstandard-2.0</TargetFrameworks>` (or something very similar), but that didn’t work.

I’ve searched the internet for a few hours now, and it appears that no one has had this problem so far; solutions for similar issues didn’t work for me.

Edit (2022-12-17): The problem disappeard after updating VS at a certain version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio issue caused by [`EnforceCodeStyleInBuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enforcecodestyleinbuild) property in .csproj file (in combination with the preview version of .NET 7). Building project with `dotnet build` instead of VS produces no warnings (or removing `EnforceCodeStyleInBuild`). Submitted [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Latest-VS-version-with-latest-NET-7-pre/10085476) for VS.

Comment: Removing `EnforceCodeStyleInBuild` worked. At first, I misunderstood your answer and put `<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>dotnet build</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>`. The first sentence is to be understood implicitly: *Remove `EnforceCodeStyleInBuild` or set it `False`.* The second sentence is related information where the warning does not show up.

Comment: @Bolpat improved wording a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Update visual studio version 2022, or use visual studio preview